# Is there extension of function from a curve on the whole space preserving smoothness?

Tags: analysis

Assume that $\alpha: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ and $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are given smooth functions. Let $t_0 \in (a,b)$.

Do there exist a $\delta>0$ and a smooth function $V: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that 
$V(\alpha(t))=f(t)$  for $t\in (t_0-\delta, t_0+\delta)$ ?

Edit. Assume additionally that $\alpha'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in (a,b)$.

Comment: The statement as posed is too strong. Let $\alpha$ be constant and $f$ be the restriction of the identity. Now $V\circ\alpha$ will be constant, whereas $f$ will not be constant on any interval $(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to assume that $\alpha$ is locally injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is enough to have $v:=\alpha'(t_0)\ne 0$.
Then in a neighbourhood of $t_0$, the map $t\mapsto \langle \alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0),v\rangle$ is injective and smooth and has a smooth inverse around $0$ with $0\mapsto t_0$. Let $g\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb (a,b)$ be a smooth function that coincides with this inverse near $0$.
Define $$V(x)=f(g(\langle x-\alpha(t_0),v\rangle)).$$
Then for $t\approx t_0$, we have 
$$ V(\alpha(t))=f(g(\langle \alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0),v\rangle))=f(t).$$